# Forwarding shell to servers without installing it

Tags: shell, zsh

is there any way how to forward a shell to a server without installing it on that box?

This is what I need to do:

I work for company where we admin X boxes and I will probably not be allowed to install zsh on those boxes. So I need somehow to forward my current shell with my settings to those boxes.

Reason ONE: I use ZSH - I don't know BASH and I don't like it.
Reason TWO: I have to forward my configuration also, cause I don't want to touch rc files of my colleges.

Many thanks for any proposed solution.

David Strejc

Answer (score 0):

If you have a shared homedir, you could do an private install in that and use it on the the other systems after mount.

Otherwise you could export an installation from your system and mount it on the clients automatically, when you log in to use it.